# Facebook Single Sign-on (SSO) stopped authorizing existing iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, single-sign-on

Our iPhone app (using iOS SDK 4.2) has been using single sign-on successfully since 5/23/2011.
Starting on 8/31/2011, when a user attempts to authorize the app for the 1st time. The Facebook App will open as usual, then exit immediately before giving an option to authorize.  The Facebook app
will then close and return to our app with the following error condition within the
custom URL scheme:

```
{
type = 15, 
string = fb257001395154://authorize#error_reason=user%5Fdenied&error=access%5Fdenied&error_description=The%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest%2E%3F%5F,
encoding = 134217984, 
base = (null)
}
```

I tested again using the latest version of the Facebook iOS SDK and received the same result.
Has anyone else seen this error?
Did Facebook make a recent change that all App pages need to implement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Authentication Fails with Facebook App Installed (iOS)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257894/authentication-fails-with-facebook-app-installed-ios)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today, an existing app was no longer able to authenticate using Facebook, I was missing the iOS Bundle ID from the Facebook app settings page. Unfortunately adding the iOS Bundle ID only gave me a new error.

To further complicate things, the app would work in the simulator but not on my device. It ended up being an issue with the Facebook app. Updating the Facebook app resolved my problem although I'm not thrilled with the idea Facebook that login is spontaneously broken for users.

Comment: worked for me (bundle ID wasnt matching). had the same symptom. worked on simulator (with SSO through safari) but didn't work on the device using SSO with the facebook app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Facebook dev site recently? They unified their app secret with their app ID maybe some modifications are required to your code

Answer (score 0):

This [duplicates my question here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7257894/authentication-fails-with-facebook-app-installed-ios).  There's a change in the Facebook's iOS app at version 3.4.4.  I had this same problem, but when I examined my iOS Bundle ID at http://developers.facebook.com/apps (click on Edit Settings for your app), I found an uppercase/lowercase mismatch in one letter of the ID.  After changing it to match 100%, the failure went away.  This still feels like a Facebook bug to me because it behaves differently depending on which version of the Facebook app is installed (or whether that app isn't installed at all).